# Dictionary KEYS python

Tags: python, java, sorting, dictionary

```
for key in Roles_dict1.keys:
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You know nothing 'Jhon' 'Swon'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
Roles_dict1 = {'CEO':1,'CTO':2,'Devops':3}
User_list = {'Jhon':'CEO','MATEW':'Devops','Bill':'CTO'}

print(sorted(User_list.items(), key=lambda x:Roles_dict1[x[1]]))
```

Result:

```
[('Jhon', 'CEO'), ('Bill', 'CTO'), ('MATEW', 'Devops')]
```

You can cast this as a dictionary by applying `dict(...)` to the resulting list.

Answer (score 1):

Should be `Roles_dict1.keys()` rather than `Roles_dict1.keys`.